# One click to profile?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed

Is there any one I can get to my profile page with only **one** click from any page like it used to be?

Why? I use it a summary of my questions. With one click, I can see all updates. Very handy if you wait for responses to few questions.

I would like to have the old good way—clicking my name will get me to my profile page.

Comment: Maybe this should be implemented with a double click. Wouldn't be a bad idea I guess. Also, you have a nice name :p

Comment: @Radek, the double-click link to your profile page or /users/recent?

Comment: @S.Mark assuming you replied to me, I meant the profile page.

Comment: well I prefer one click to name = profile, click to arrow = new menu ...

Comment: btw my surname starts with S (Š) too. Are you sure you aren't me? :-p

Comment: let's wait for @Jeff to comment on that ...

Comment: @Radek mine starts with just an S, not an Š. I am not you. You are not me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eeeek! What happened to my envelope?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)

Comment: Yes! This new feature is annoying as hell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now the behavior, the popup shows on hover, clicking your name once again goes to the profile :)

Answer (score 4):

Why can't the drop down just appear, when I hoover over it and the click works as before?
Don't tell you can't do that we have that doubtful feature with all the tag fields.

Comment: eek, no, with that and the tags 'popout-on-hover' feature, the SE pages will become a minefield where your mouse can never rest safely :(

Comment: No, having to wait half a second, or more, for frequently used links is just aggravating.

Comment: @Brock - No reaosn to wait half a second, if that were to be implement I would think that it should be a "no-delay" popup. So long as it did not cover your username, you could still click the username to get to the profile. Solves the "one click to profile" problem and then "wait half a second problem". Dosn't solve the minefield problem of course though... But I don't really see an issue with the popups...

Comment: @All - if i'm not mistaken, has this idea been implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the greasemonkey script that attach mouseover event to that.

So you can go to your profile with one mouse click :-)

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/98756.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/98756)

Comment: @Mark: how should it work? I've never used greasemonkey before. It is installed but what's next? Would this work accross all SE sites?

Comment: @Radek, for greasemonkey, please see http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info , but anything may break because currently they are redesigning the page.

Comment: Mark - then what's the point of a greasemonkey script if it's liable to break? This whole greasemonkey bodging thing is such a cop out, generally speaking.

Comment: @Kev it's not a fix by any means, it's a workaround, and like all workarounds they may no longer apply if the thing they're working around changes

Comment: SO Implemented mouseover as default, so this is now no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't your profile go straight to your profile with a click like before and the **menu popup when clicking on the little symbol to the left of your profile name**?

Comment: The arrow would have to be a bit bigger for that to be reasonable. It's a pretty small target right now.

Comment: @mmyers - sure, wasn't the symbol from before bigger? They could use the old symbol, which I happened to like, or make the current one bigger.